# C# Linq PDF file write/ Read SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, pdf

I want to store the PDF file in the database using C# and linq.

SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FATURA_PDF]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FATURA_NO] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [PDF_IMAGE] [VARBINARY](max) NULL,
    [GORULDU] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [GUID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NULL
)
```

PDF image columns pdf file write / read code?

Comment: Please note Stack Overflow isn’t “write code for me” site. If you try to do it yourself and run into specific problems you can ask for help with those. As it is your question is better answered by a tutorial, many of which you’ll find with your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to convert your file into binary then put it in your insert query :

```
private byte[] GetBinaryFile(filename)
{
     byte[] bytes;
     using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
          bytes = new byte[file.Length];
          file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
     }
     return bytes;
}
```

Comment: linq read varbinary(max)  pdf file wiewer ?

Comment: You should set PDF_Image value, so you should convert your data into binary array and then set it.

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/Y6XByk.jpg    save database  but  read code

Comment: I can't open it

Comment: https://ibb.co/iM3TR9  see new link

Comment: If you have byte array as string and you want to convert it to byte[], use this : `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)`

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
var oFATURA_PDF = new FATURA_PDF() {
            .....
        };
using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
{
    oFATURA_PDF.PDF_IMAGE = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
}

db.FATURA_PDF.Add(oFATURA_PDF);
db.SaveChanges();
```